# Flexible filter with OR

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter, ag-grid

I am using AG-GRID with Vue 3. I have filters in a sidebar. It all works fine. Each row has an id. What I want to change is the logic in the filter - I want to add logic so that all id's within a supplied list pass. So the filter pass logic is:

(filter1 passes AND filter2 passes AND filter3 passes etc.) OR id is in list.

[The background is that I am using filters on a table, but also selecting rows on a leaflet map, and I want the map selected rows plus the table filtered rows to be seen in the table].

I guess I could do this with multiple custom filters and adapt the filterpass code, but this seems very tedious.

Is there an easier way?

If I could generate 95% of a custom filter from an inbuilt filter, it would help, but I fear that is not easy either.

This article does not describe what I want, as it descibes OR filtering followed by AND filtering, if I understand correctly.

https://blog.ag-grid.com/advanced-filtering-in-ag-grid-using-or-filtering-conditions/

Comment: As an example, PowerBI can use OR conditions, as explained below between filters, but it is not completely trtivial https://apexinsights.net/blog/or-xor-slicing

Comment: Maybe an approach might be to have the filter NOT filter on any rows which have been selected? Whci would involve some extra functionality and options in ag-grid. Or have two tables, the first with filtered rows, the second with selected rows 
 which are NOT filtered ? Clutching at straws a bit. What currently happens if you filter, and then select rows programmatically? Are any filtered rows ignored?

Comment: Maybe this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74319462/how-to-ignore-selected-rows-when-filtering-using-floating-filters-in-ag-grid

Comment: Extending a class seemed like a good idea (I have about 20 years Java experience) but it turned out to be a nightmare. vue-class-component seems to be unsupported and different versions, I couldn't get anything to work.

Comment: A bit of a story. Struggled all day with extending classes, but ended up with a way to do it outside of TS. But on examination of ag-grid, it really is not suitable to extend SetFilter. So I am now using TextColumnFilter and defining my own textMatcher, and tomorrow I will make a number Custom Filter. Note - I had to install the latest version of ag-grid to get it working.

Comment: Got a number filter working for integers. It was actually quite easy - you can use a TextFilter to handle numbers. I just defined a textMatcher and checked the data types, and could use a range filter by accessing the filter details for the column to get a to and from. Finish it off tomorrow after a new years eve drink. Will post when happy.